# Is a nextTick() callback run just before any other JS code or just after?

Tags: javascript, node.js

An excerpt from [the docs](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#process-nexttick):

> `process.nextTick()` is not technically part of the event loop. Instead,
> the nextTickQueue will be processed **after** the current operation is
> completed, regardless of the current phase of the event loop. Here, **(1) an
> operation is defined as a transition from the underlying C/C++
> handler**, and handling the JavaScript that needs to be executed.

One from [the node js blog](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v0.10.0/#faster-process-nexttick):

> In v0.10, **(2) nextTick handlers are run right after each call from C++
> into JavaScript**. That means that, **(3) if your JavaScript code calls
> process.nextTick, then the callback will fire as soon as the code runs
> to completion, but before going back to the event loop**.

Maybe I start to fail to see straight at late night but it seems for me **(1)** and **(2)** means one thing and **(3)** is about something altogether different. That is, **(1)/(2)** state a `nextTick()` callback (which was scheduled by JS beforehand) would be executed as soon as C/C++ code transfers control back to the JS side. On the contrary, **(3)** relates that the callback should be run just after JS code scheduled it, without making an entrance into the C based Event Loop.

Can anyone provide some clarification? If my I/O callback uses `setImmediate()` for another one will the latter executed "on the spot" or the control flow visits the Event Loop at first?

Comment: "*a `nextTick()` callback would be executed as soon as C/C++ code transfers control back to the JS side.*" - no. C/C++ does not transfer control *back* to JS, it does *call* the JS "operation". I understand all three descriptions that at the end of these calls into JS, i.e. right after the JS code returns, the `nextTick` callbacks are run.

Comment: Why is your last sentence referring to `setImmediate` instead of `nextTick`?